# How do you create an event in nodejs-webkit for when the user focuses another application?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, node-webkit

I would like to detect when the user has given focus to another application (for example google chrome) and then read in as much information about that application as is possible, title, file name, description etc

What's the best of achieving this on windows?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onblur()` is the event listener to realise of that event within your node-webkit app.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var Q = require("q");
var runCommand = function(cmd, args) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var child = spawn(cmd, args);

        child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { 
            child.stdout += buffer.toString();
            deferred.notify();
        });

        child.stdout.on('end',function(){
            deferred.resolve(child.stdout);
        });

        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stderr: ' + data);
            deferred.reject(new Error("stdeerr: " + data));  
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };



window.onblur=function(){
        runCommand(command, args).then(processOutputFunction,errorCallBack);

}
```

With the snippet above you can call whatever 3rd party library or powershell command to get the specific information you need. Regarding focus on Windows platform I suggest you to take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus.

Cannot help further regarding that specifics